# No es posible seleccionar la opción "Recomendar cierre" en revisiones de publicaciones de baja calidad

Tags: bug, estado-completado, colas-de-revisión, votos-de-cierre

Algo extraño me pasa desde esta mañana, cuando ingreso para realizar las revisiones de baja calidad no funciona el botón <kbd>Enviar</kbd> cuando selecciono ***Recomendar cierre***, intenté refrescando la pagina y cambiando de navegador, pero si selecciono la opción ***Se ve bien*** funciona bien.

¿A alguien mas le sucede?

Dejo un gif para que vean de lo que hablo:

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Dejo un segundo gif mostrando la consola, hay dos errores allí pero según veo no tienen mucho que ver con mi problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El segundo error que sale en la consola es:

```
jquery.min.js:4 GET https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/undefined/votes?_=1614181869247 404
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
d @ full.es.js?v=4929e631af9d:8
f @ full.es.js?v=4929e631af9d:8
Z @ full.es.js?v=4929e631af9d:9
init @ full.es.js?v=4929e631af9d:9
o @ review-v2-transpiled.es.js?v=6a8fcfe4f3eb:1
success @ review-v2-transpiled.es.js?v=6a8fcfe4f3eb:1
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
y @ jquery.min.js:4
c @ jquery.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
u @ review-v2-transpiled.es.js?v=6a8fcfe4f3eb:1
c @ review-v2-transpiled.es.js?v=6a8fcfe4f3eb:1
(anonymous) @ review-v2-transpiled.es.js?v=6a8fcfe4f3eb:1
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120278/discussion-on-question-by-israel-icm-no-es-posible-seleccionar-la-opcion-recome).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He reparado el problema. Básicamente, cuando un usuario quien puede recomendar cierre (y no puede cerrar) una pregunta trata de hacerlo, el link escondido “Cerrar” no esta incluido en la página (por que el usuario no puede cerrar). La acción “Recomendar cierre” depende en el link escondido para cargar el dialogo de cerrar, entonces, la acción falla sin errores (gracias a jQuery!). Para reparar el problema, modifiqué la lógica del menú para que incluir el link escondido para todos los usuarios. ¡Muchas gracias por tu reporte, es un error grande!

El build con la corrección se hizo hoy (25 de Febrero de 2021) alreadedor de 1:50 pm UTC, por lo que ya debería estar solucionado en el sitio.